# local variable 'form1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1F92.jpg)i want to allow users to update their profile informations but my problem is that when i submit the form it shows me this error and i can't see where the error is !!

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_u = UpdateUser(request.POST)
        profile_u = UpdateProfile(request.POST)

        if user_u.is_valid() and profile_u.is_valid():
            request.user.username = user_u.cleaned_data['username']
            request.user.first_name = user_u.cleaned_data['first_name']
            request.user.last_name = user_u.cleaned_data['last_name']
            request.user.email = user_u.cleaned_data['email']
            request.user.save()
            prf = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            prf.Zip_code = profile_u.cleaned_data['Zip_code']
            prf.Phone = profile_u.cleaned_data['Phone']
            prf.save()
            return redirect(reverse('profile'))

    else:
        data1 = {'username': request.user.username, 'email': request.user.email,
                 'first_name': request.user.first_name, 'last_name': request.user.last_name}
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        data2 = {'Phone': profile.Phone, 'Zip_code': profile.Zip_code}
        form1 = UpdateUser(initial=data1)
        form2 = UpdateProfile(initial=data2)

    return render(request, 'store/updateprofile.html', {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2})
```

Comment: What if the method is `POST` but `user_u.is_valid() and profile_u.is_valid()` does not hold?

Comment: The traceback - which you didn't post - tells you exactly where the error is.

Comment: can you be more specifique ?

Comment: i think the error is in this line :                                                                         return render(request, 'store/updateprofile.html', {'form1': form1, 'form2': form2})

Comment: @bouzianeyacine I already know where the problem is (it's quite obvious), it's not me who need the information but you who should use it (hint: tracebacks are here to help you debug the problem, so read them carefully). Ok now you know that at this line Python complains about name 'form1' not being defined, re-read your code and check where this name is defined, and how it could happen that it's not. Hint: names are only defined if the code that defines them is actually executed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please re-read my profile - I obviously don't need to be explained what is wrong with this code xD (nb: I'm not the OP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might probably help if you use *consistent* variable names over the entire scope of the method. Here in the `POST` case you use `user_u` and `profile_u`, whereas in the `GET` case (the last `else`), you will use `form1` and `form2`.

As a result a POST request where (at least) one of the forms is invalid, will result in a `render(..)` call, but without setting `form1` and `form2`.

In your view you also do a lot of things that are typically handled by a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), so I propose that you call the `profile_u.save()` (and if not yet done, transform these forms into `ModelForm`).

Finally you can use `instance=...` to load the form with "initial values".

If we take these changes into account, we obtain the following view:

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request):
    prf = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_u = UpdateUser(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_u = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=prf)

        if user_u.is_valid() and profile_u.is_valid():
            user_u.save()
            profile_u.save()
            return redirect(reverse('profile'))

    else:
        user_u = UpdateUser(instance=request.user)
        profile_u = UpdateProfile(instance=prf)

    return render(request, 'store/updateprofile.html', {'form1': user_u, 'form2': profile_u})
```